# How to access Content Provider in Bixby Programming

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am an amateur programmer and I would need to get the Login Details / Authorization token from another app to be able to make API calls since the data to be returned from what they ask is based on their specific account.

I have scoured their documentation but I am unable to find anything that even remotely points to accessing other app's data.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Regards

Comment: Hi, does the target API support oAuth? If so, it is most appropriate way to access the user specific data by following standard oAuth workflow. With oAuth, user is directed to Content Provider website for authentication and your capsule will receive auth token to access user data. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MohanaRao Hi, thank you for replying. Yes, the target API supports oAuth. I was hoping to avoid logging in again in Bixby itself so the user can have a smooth experience. Do you know if it is possible to open the keyboard in Bixby to input text? Bixby correctly interpreting the dictated password with special characters would be almost impossible.

Comment: Bixby oAuth flow follows regular oAuth flow on mobile with keyboard input.

Comment: @MohanaRao Got it Mohana, Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help..!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:(5/24/2021)**
This was a while ago. I'm not working on Bixby now. Bixby is very dynamic and fast evolving Voice Platform.
There may be a better way to do this in latest Bixby Platform.
Please refer to the documentation and reach out to the technical support team.

**Original Answer**

does the target API support oAuth? If so, it is most appropriate way to access the user specific data by following standard oAuth workflow.

With oAuth, user is directed to Content Provider website for authentication and your capsule will receive auth token to access user data.

Bixby oAuth flow follows regular oAuth flow on mobile with keyboard input. So it is a standard UX without much friction.